# Change namespace to include a parent namespace (OLD -> NEW.OLD)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

How can I add a parent namespace to an existing namespace? I want to change all occurrences of `OLD` to `NEW.OLD`. Is there a way to do that without manually updating every occurrence?

A simple `Rename` doesn't seem to work like it does when renaming from `OLD` to `NEWOLD`.

Comment: JetBrains ReSharper is your friend, adjust namespaces with one click, plus 1000 other refactoring tools coolness

Comment: @LukeHutton, VS already has what is needed by this poster.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just an awesome tool that will save you time programming, which equals money

Comment: @LukeHutton a) Thanks. No resharper (yet)... b) About your `Fair enough` - are you agreeing that VS has it? If so - please post your answer, because the current answer doesn't work.

Comment: Yah sorry, I could only comment to the fact R# has it, don't really use much VS tooling so cannot answer, free 30 day trial if your in a bind

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio you can right-click on the `OLD` namespace and rename it to `NEW.OLD`. It should refactor all the relevant code from `OLD` to `NEW.OLD`

Comment: I've already tried that and it did nothing. Perhaps I'm doing this wrong. Can you describe the exact steps to do this? What I do is: change the namespace, rename, VS does nothing.

Comment: @ispiro: double-click the `OLD`, press `F2` key (or right-click, choose 'rename'), type `NEW.OLD`, press enter. If you're using VS2015, then the changes will be done in-place, if pre-2015, then a dialog will appear.

Comment: I did that. `F2` does nothing. And `Edit->refactor->rename` just gives me the option of renaming `OLD` to `OLD`. i.e. nothing.

Comment: Can you please try your answer and tell me what happens.

Comment: @ispiro: I posted exactly what I did as a trial before I posted it. If it gives you the option to rename it, it's a type-in box where you can enter a new name.

Comment: Thanks. This is very strange. When I click rename - it doesn't let me enter a new name. It just asks me if I want to preview the changes (which I didn't even make yet...). I'm using VS2015 Community without any add-ons. Perhaps you're using a different version or using ReSharper?

Comment: @ispiro: I'm using the VS2015 Enterprise edition. I thought this was base functionality, maybe I'm wrong. Not using ReSharper.

Comment: This should definitely work for you. Can you add screenshots showing what you are experiencing.